# Certain decompositions of decomposable Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

> Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a decomposable Banach space (i.e. a topological direct sum of infinite-dimensional subspaces, say $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathcal{B}$). Can one always obtain another decomposition $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{U}\oplus\mathcal{V}$ (of infinite-dimensional closed subspaces $\mathcal{U}$ with $\mathcal{V}$) with a continuous linear map $T\colon \mathcal{U}\to\mathcal{V}$ that admits a continuous right or left inverse?

If any partial/conditional results or known reformulations exist, that will be most appreciated.

Comment: Sure, you can always adjoin some finite-dimensional subspace of $V$ to $U$.

Comment: @Tomasz Kania. Could I kindly ask that you expand on your suggestion. (Seems I should easily see it but I’m not getting it right away ).

Comment: Finite-dimensional subspaces are always complemented, so write $U = U_1 \oplus F_1$ with $F_1$ finite-dimensional and take $U^\prime = U_1$ and $V^\prime = V + F_1$.

Comment: @Tomasz Kania. I believe I should have added some conditions. I expect the map $T$ to be surjective if the kernel is complemented and to be injective if the closed image is complemented. Equivalently, $T$ should either have a continuous right inverse or a left inverse (I have re-edited for clarity). Would (a modification of) your suggestion still work in this case?

Comment: Yes, of course. A subspace is complemented whenever there is a continuous linear projection thereonto. By the Hahn--Banach theorem, finite-dimensional subspaces are always complemented, so such decompositions are never unique as you may interchange finite-dimensional pieces.

Comment: Tomek, the OP wants $U$ to contain a complemented copy of $V$ or $V$ to contain a complemented copy of $U$ and $X=U\oplus V$.

Comment: To get an example, take two HI spaces $U$ and $V$ s.t. every bounded linear operator from $U$ to $V$ is strictly singular and apply the Edelstien-Wojtasczcyk theorem (see vol.1 of Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri Theorem 2.c.13) to $X := U \oplus V$,